Java Maven automation test running fine locally, but returning a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running the same tests on AWS
I have a Java Maven regression suite that I run against Chrome on AWS that used to run fine until a few months ago. After solving an issue with Chrome not installing int he instance run, the error now seems to be Java based.
The tests are run in a Java Maven project using JUnit and Cucumber. They run fine when ran locally using IntelliJ on my local machine, but when I execute them in AWS Codebuild, I am faced with the same error for each test scenario run:
[ERROR] My Results Screen.I can view the results for a dataslice on the My Results screen -- Time elapsed: 0.026 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.emprisautomationtest.stepDefinitions.Hooks
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53)
    at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:64)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreHookDefinition.execute(CoreHookDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.HookDefinitionMatch.runStep(HookDefinitionMatch.java:21)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:81)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:53)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:90)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.lambda$run$0(PickleRunners.java:151)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:136)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:136)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:148)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:144)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:137)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:199)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runFeatures$6(CucumberExecutionContext.java:147)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.execute(CucumberExecutionContext.java:162)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runFeatures(CucumberExecutionContext.java:145)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$StartAndFinishTestRun.evaluate(Cucumber.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.emprisautomationtest.config.GUIConfig [in thread "main"]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53)
    at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:64)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreHookDefinition.execute(CoreHookDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.HookDefinitionMatch.runStep(HookDefinitionMatch.java:21)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:81)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:53)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:90)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.lambda$run$0(PickleRunners.java:151)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:136)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:136)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:148)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:144)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:137)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:199)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runFeatures$6(CucumberExecutionContext.java:147)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.execute(CucumberExecutionContext.java:162)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runFeatures(CucumberExecutionContext.java:145)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$StartAndFinishTestRun.evaluate(Cucumber.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:240)
    ... 6 more

The tests are run on AWS Codebuild on Ubuntu 7.0.
The YAML file used to run the test is as follows:
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - java --version
      - sudo yum clean all
      - sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
      - sudo yum update -y
      - sudo yum install wget -y
      - wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
      - sudo yum localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm -y
      - google-chrome-stable --version
      - pip3 install selenium
      - mvn $PREPROD_CREDENTIALS -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Regression and @GUI" test -gs ./settings.xml
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - mvn surefire-report:report-only
reports:
  arn:aws:codebuild:eu-west-2:161668806093:report-group/empris-automation-gui-test-preprod-reportGroupCucumberJson:
    files:
      - 'TEST-com.emprisautomationtest.apiDefinition.RunCukesTest.xml'
    base-directory: 'target'
    discard-paths: yes
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
cache:
  paths:
    - '/root/.m2/**/*'

The POM file is up to date and as follows:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.emprisautomationtest</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.emprisautomationtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>com.emprisautomationtest</name>
    <description>com.emprisautomationtest</description>

    <properties>
        <aws.java.sdk.version>1.12.778</aws.java.sdk.version>
        <commons.codec.version>1.17.1</commons.codec.version>
        <cucumber.core.version>7.20.1</cucumber.core.version>
        <cucumber.extentreport.version>3.1.1</cucumber.extentreport.version>
        <cucumber.html.version>0.2.7</cucumber.html.version>
        <cucumber.html.version.plugin>0.2.7</cucumber.html.version.plugin>
        <cucumber.junit.version>7.20.1</cucumber.junit.version>
        <cucumber.java.version>7.20.1</cucumber.java.version>
        <cucumber.jvm.deps.version>1.0.6</cucumber.jvm.deps.version>
        <cucumber.reporting.version>5.8.4</cucumber.reporting.version>
        <extentreports.version>5.1.2</extentreports.version>
        <extentreports.cucumber7.adapter.version>1.14.0</extentreports.cucumber7.adapter.version>
        <gherkin.version>30.0.4</gherkin.version>
        <gherkin.jvm.deps.version.plugin>1.0.6</gherkin.jvm.deps.version.plugin>
        <googleauth.version>1.5.0</googleauth.version>
        <gson.version>2.11.0</gson.version>
        <guava.version>33.3.1-jre</guava.version>
        <hamcrest.all.version>1.3</hamcrest.all.version>
        <hamcrest.date.version>2.0.8</hamcrest.date.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.14</httpclient.version>
        <jackson.annotations.version>2.18.1</jackson.annotations.version>
        <jackson.core.version>2.18.1</jackson.core.version>
        <jackson.databind.version>2.18.1</jackson.databind.version>
        <jakarta.xml.bind.version>4.0.2</jakarta.xml.bind.version>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <javafaker.version>1.0.2</javafaker.version>
        <jaxb.runtime.version>4.0.5</jaxb.runtime.version>
        <json.path.assert.version>2.9.0</json.path.assert.version>
        <json.simple.version>1.1.1</json.simple.version>
        <json.version>20230227</json.version>
        <junit.version>4.13.2</junit.version>
        <log4j.version>2.24.2</log4j.version>
        <log4j.api.verion>2.24.2</log4j.api.verion>
        <log4j.core.version>2.24.2</log4j.core.version>
        <maven.assembly.plugin.version>3.7.1</maven.assembly.plugin.version>
        <maven.clean.version>3.4.0</maven.clean.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.13.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.cucumber.reporting.version>5.8.2</maven.cucumber.reporting.version>
        <maven.javadoc.plugin.version>3.11.1</maven.javadoc.plugin.version>
        <maven.jxr.plugin.version>3.6.0</maven.jxr.plugin.version>
        <maven.site.plugin.version>4.0.0-M16</maven.site.plugin.version>
        <maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.5.2</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
        <maven.surefire.report.plugin.version>3.5.2</maven.surefire.report.plugin.version>
        <reporting.plugin.version>5.0.0</reporting.plugin.version>
        <restassured.version>5.5.0</restassured.version>
        <selenium.version>4.27.0</selenium.version>
        <selenium.server.version>3.141.59</selenium.server.version>
        <slf4j.log4j12.version>2.0.16</slf4j.log4j12.version>
        <webdrivermanager.version>5.9.2</webdrivermanager.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.java.sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.codec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.java.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vimalselvam/cucumber-extentsreport -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.extentreport.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>${extentreports.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.grasshopper/extentreports-cucumber7-adapter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber7-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>${extentreports.cucumber7.adapter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>${gherkin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.warrenstrange</groupId>
            <artifactId>googleauth</artifactId>
            <version>${googleauth.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.databind.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.xml.bind.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>${javafaker.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.runtime.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
            <version>${json.path.assert.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.cucumber.reporting.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.assembly.plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.monochromata.cucumber/reporting-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.monochromata.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>reporting-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${reporting.plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${restassured.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.server.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.bodar.com</id>
            <url>http://repo.bodar.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
                <version>${cucumber.html.version.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
                <version>${cucumber.jvm.deps.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>${cucumber.reporting.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
                <version>${gherkin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>gherkin-jvm-deps</artifactId>
                <version>${gherkin.jvm.deps.version.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>${gson.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>${guava.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                <version>${hamcrest.all.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.exparity</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-date</artifactId>
                <version>${hamcrest.date.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>${json.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                <version>${json.simple.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.api.verion}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.core.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.cucumber.reporting.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>analysis-ui-test</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-html-reports
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.javadoc.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.jxr.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.report.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.site.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-report</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <argLine>
                        --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED
                    </argLine>
                    <rerunFailingTestsCount>1</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.log4j12.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
                <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
                <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- ... -->
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.report.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.jxr.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>


Why do you have defined a maven plugin as dependency? That is simply wrong...You have also defined a lot of dependencies like guava, hamcrest-all as plugins which also simply wrong...

Some of this was done by the last person who set up the repository before me. Would this be related to my issue or something that needs to be changed anyway?

I simply don't know... without the full pom a full log etc. and seeing some parts of the code it's really hard to even guess....

Thanks anyway. I'm moving the plugins to the dependencies for now to see if that helps.
THe full POM is in the original post, but the full log is incredibly long.

No. Remove the plugins from the dependencies ... only define a plugin if it's really plugin .. you need to learn the difference between a plugin and a dependency...
